# How to know group administator in linux

Tags: linux, administrator

I saw that: `sudo gpasswd -A <admin-name> <group-name>` can set Admin for a group and a group can have more than one Admin.

How can I show all Admins of a group if it doesn't even show in `/etc/group`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group admins can be seen in /etc/gshadow.

Check the man page gshadow for the description of the file.